# PHP Unlink doesn't fully delete file but converts it to a 0kb file

Tags: php

I can see that the image I am trying to delete using unlink in PHP doesn't get deleted but I can see the same file, corrupted this time and its size is 0kb

My code:

```
$file_pointer = fopen($onoma, 'w');  

// Use unlink() function to delete a file  
if (!unlink($file_pointer)) {  
    echo ("$file_pointer cannot be deleted due to an error");  
}  
else {  
    echo ("$file_pointer has been deleted");  
}
```

Plus, the error I am getting is given below:

```
Warning: unlink() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\\\\\\delete_image.php on line 80
The image has been deleted.
```

Comment: It works only without the context ```$file_pointer = $onoma```

Comment: That's how [unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) works, what is your question? No need to open a file before you want to delete it

Comment: hmm.. unlink needs as parameter the file not the descriptor

Comment: As pointed out on the duplicate, opening the file with `'w'` resets the file to 0kb anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, "unlink() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path". Or, as [the official manual says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php):

> Parameters
>
> - filename: Path to the file.

So rather than opening the file and passing the file-pointer, you should just pass the file path:

```
if (!unlink($onoma)) {
// ...
```